# HttpServletRequest reading large post body - unable to read all data, wait for all chunks

Tags: java, apache, http, tomcat, servlets

When I read the data like this

```
    String body = null;

    try {
        body = IOUtils.toString(request.getReader());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //
    }
```

Not all the data is read. The "content-length" header contains the correct length of the data, but it looks like `IOUtils.toString` does not wait for all the chunks.

This old verbose code works, but I'm wondering if there is a modern way that waits until all the data is read:

```
    String body = null; 
            try {
                ServletInputStream in = request.getInputStream();
                String reqLengthString = request.getHeader("content-length");
                int requestLength = 0;

                try {
                    requestLength = Integer.valueOf(reqLengthString).intValue();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return doForecastErrorResponse(response,"Invalid Content Length");
                }
                Debug.logInfo("RequestLength: "+requestLength, MODULE);

                int i = -1;
                while (requestLength > 0) {
                    byte[] line = new byte[8192];
                    i = waitingReadLine(in, line, 0, 8192, requestLength);
                    requestLength -= i;
                    if (Debug.verboseOn()) {
                        Debug.logVerbose("remaining request length: "+requestLength, MODULE);
                        Debug.logVerbose("data this grab: "+new String(line), MODULE);
                    }

                    jb.append(new String(line));
                }

                body = jb.toString().trim();
                if (Debug.verboseOn()) {
                    Debug.logVerbose("String: "+body, MODULE);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                return doForecastErrorResponse(response,"Error reading input."+e.getMessage());

            }


private static int waitingReadLine(ServletInputStream in, byte[] buf, int off, int len, int reqLen) throws IOException {
        int i = -1;

        while (((i = in.readLine(buf, off, len)) == -1) && (reqLen > 0)) {
            int waitCount = 0;
            int MAX_WAITS = 30;
            int WAIT_INTERVAL = 1000;

            if (Debug.verboseOn()) Debug.logVerbose("Waiting for read line", MODULE);
            if (waitCount > MAX_WAITS) {
                if (Debug.verboseOn()) Debug.logVerbose("Waited " + waitCount + " times, bailing out while still expecting " + reqLen + " bytes.", MODULE);
                throw new IOException("waited " + waitCount + " times, bailing out while still expecting " +
                        reqLen + " bytes.");
            }
            waitCount++;
            long endMS = new Date().getTime() + WAIT_INTERVAL;

            while (endMS > (new Date().getTime())) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(WAIT_INTERVAL);
                } catch (Exception e3) {
                    if (Debug.verboseOn()) Debug.logVerbose("Exception waiting for read line"+ e3.getMessage(), MODULE);
                }
            }
            if (Debug.verboseOn()) Debug.logVerbose("Waited " + (new Date().getTime() - (endMS - WAIT_INTERVAL)) + " ms", MODULE);
        }
        return i;
    }
```

Comment: You could try engaging one of the `IOUtils.readFully()` methods to read the data into a `Buffer` or array, and then convert the result to a `String`.

Comment: what data are you trying to read?

Comment: @ScaryWombat it's a JSON Object

Comment: @JohnBollinger what do I set the size of the char[] to? If I set it to the content-length, I can an error  ```java.io.EOFException: Length to read: 11912 actual: 8129``` I think the chunk size is 8129

Comment: @SumamaWaheed, the content-length gives the length in *bytes*, not characters.  The count of (encoded) characters is not necessarily the same.  It is not clear whether a solution is available via this route, but if it is, then you should probably read `content-length` *bytes* into a byte array, and then convert the result to a `String` according to the encoding specified by the client, or else according to the appropriate network protocol's default encoding, which is not necessarily *Java*'s default encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: actually the trick was to use `getInputStream` instead of `getReader`:

```
IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream());
```

Posting answer from comment from @John Bollinger

```
    byte[] buffer = new byte[requestLength];
    IOUtils.readFully(request.getInputStream(), buffer);
    body = new String(buffer);
```